# How do I read the HITRAN2012 database into MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

The HITRAN database is a listing of molecular rotational-vibrational transitions. It is given in a text file where each line is 160 characters, with fixed width fields defining molecule, isotope, etc. The format is well documented, and there is even a program on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26707-voigt-lineshape-spectrum-simulation-gui) that will read in the database and simulate a portion of the spectrum. However, I need to read in a specific portion of the spectrum and then use it to do some fitting to a measured spectrum, so I need something much more custom.

As given in the comment section of that function, as well as elsewhere, the following line should read each line in properly:

```
database = which('HITRAN2012.par');
fid = fopen(database);
hitran = textscan(fid,'%2u%1u%12f%10f%10f%5f%5f%10f%4f%8f%15c%15c%15c%15c%6c%12c%1c%7f%7f','delimiter','','whitespace','');
fclose(fid);
```

The first two fields denote the molecule code, which runs from 1-47, and the isotope code which runs from 1-9.

Unfortunately, molecules 1-9 do not have a leading zero, and no matter what I do, it seems to silently confuse MATLAB.  If I load in the entire database and then type

```
unique(hitran{1})
```

I do not get the numbers 1-47, but I get 10-92 with a few numbers missing. As far as I can figure, when MATLAB encounters a leading space, it shifts the line over and then pads the end, so that ' 12' becomes '12', but I'm not exactly sure. I have also tried

```
hitran = textscan(fid,'%160c','delimiter','\n','whitespace','');
```

and then tried to parse the resulting strings, but that also sometimes gets confused by the first space.

For instance, the first water line looks like

```
exampleHitranLine = ' 14    0.007002 1.165E-32 2.071E-14.05870.305  818.00670.590.000000          0 0 0          0 0 0  7  5  2        7  5  3      005540 02227 5 2 0    90.0   90.0';
```

The first bit of code comes across this line and returns `'14'` instead of `' 1'` and `'4'`. If I just read in a subset that only contains molecule 1 (as in this example), then the second method of reading works fine. If I try to read in the entire database, however, the lines with molecule 1-9 are shifted the the left, which messes up all the other fields.

I should note that I've tried reading the numerical fields both as floats and as integers, and neither gives satisfactory results. The entire database in text form is nearly 700 MB, and so I need something that works as efficiently as possible.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer as to why this is happening, but I do have a solution. If anyone has an answer as to why, I'd be happy to accept it.

It is the leading space that is screwing things up. MATLAB is being a little too clever, and when `textscan` encounters a leading space, it decides that it's extra and discards it and moves on to the next two characters. To get it to properly read in the file, I had to go line by line and test whether the first character is a space and then replace it with a leading zero, like this:

```
database = which('HITRAN2012_First100Lines.par');

fileParams = dir(database);
K = fileParams.bytes/162;
hitran = cell(K,19);

fid = fopen(database);
for k = 1:K
hitranTemp = fgetl(fid);
if abs(hitranTemp(1)) == 32;
    hitranTemp(1) = '0';
end
    hitran(k,:) = deal(textscan(hitranTemp,'%2u%1u%12f%10f%10f%5f%5f%10f%4f%8f%15c%15c%15c%15c%6c%12c%1c%7f%7f','delimiter','','whitespace',''));
end
fclose(fid);
```

I'm working in MATLAB 2013a. Should I consider this to be a bug and report it? Is there some reason that the leading space should be gobbled up like this?

**Update:**

My workaround above was slow, but worked. Then I had to process the HITEMP database, which is several times larger, so I finally did submit a support ticket to MathWorks. The workaround suggested by MathWorks technical support is to read everything in as text and then convert. This saves a lot of disk reads and works.

```
fileParams = dir(database);

fid = fopen(database);

hitran = textscan(fid,'%2c%1c%12c%10c%10c%5c%5c%10c%4c%8c%15c%15c%15c%15c%6c%12c%1c%7c%7c','delimiter','','whitespace','');

fclose(fid);

moleculeNumber = uint8(str2num(hitran{1}));
isotopologueNumber = uint8(str2num(hitran{2});
vacuumWavenumber = str2num(hitran{3});
...
etc.
```

Depending on the application, for larger databases one would probably want to do this [in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578346/excessively-large-overhead-in-matlab-mat-file) rather than all at once.

He also said he would forward the behavior to the development team for consideration in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

I [have a new file on the FileExchange that will read in HITRAN 2004+ format data](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45819-load-hitran-2004+-data). Please try it out and let me know if there are any issues with it.

Comment: At least on my computer running MATLAB 2013A on Windows 7, your code does exactly the same thing as mine. It gobbles the first space and moves the whole line over, so that H2O (molecule ID ' 1'), for instance, shows up as ammonia (molecule ID '11').

Comment: Check out my update below for a workaround suggested by Mathworks.