# Excessively large overhead in MATLAB .mat file

Tags: matlab

I am parsing a large text file full of data and then saving it to disk as a *.mat file so that I can easily load in only parts of it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393726/how-do-i-read-the-hitran2012-database-into-matlab) for more information on reading in the files, and [here](http://hitran.iao.ru/survey) for the data). To do so, I read in one line at a time, parse the line, and then append it to the file. The problem is that the file itself is >3 orders of magnitude larger than the data contained therein!

Here is a stripped down version of my code:

```
database = which('01_hit12.par');
[directory,filename,~] = fileparts(database);
matObj = matfile(fullfile(directory,[filename '.mat']),'Writable',true);

fidr = fopen(database);
hitranTemp = fgetl(fidr);
k = 1;
while ischar(hitranTemp)
    if abs(hitranTemp(1)) == 32;
        hitranTemp(1) = '0';
    end

    hitran = textscan(hitranTemp,'%2u%1u%12f%10f%10f%5f%5f%10f%4f%8f%15c%15c%15c%15c%6u%2u%2u%2u%2u%2u%2u%1c%7f%7f','delimiter','','whitespace','');

    matObj.moleculeNumber(1,k)      = uint8(hitran{1});
    matObj.isotopeologueNumber(1,k) = uint8(hitran{2});
    matObj.vacuumWavenumber(1,k)    = hitran{3};
    matObj.lineIntensity(1,k)       = hitran{4};
    matObj.airWidth(1,k)            = single(hitran{6});
    matObj.selfWidth(1,k)           = single(hitran{7});
    matObj.lowStateE(1,k)           = single(hitran{8});
    matObj.tempDependWidth(1,k)     = single(hitran{9});
    matObj.pressureShift(1,k)       = single(hitran{10});

    if rem(k,1e4) == 0;
        display(sprintf('line %u (%2.2f)',k,100*k/K));
    end
    hitranTemp = fgetl(fidr);
    k = k + 1;
end
fclose(fidr);
```

I stopped the code after 13,813 of the 224,515 lines had been parsed because it had been taking a very long time and the file size was getting huge, but the last printout indicated that I had only just cleared 10k lines. I cleared the memory, and then ran:

```
S = whos('-file','01_hit12.mat');
fileBytes = sum([S.bytes]);

T = dir(which('01_hit12.mat'));
diskBytes = T.bytes;

disp([fileBytes diskBytes diskBytes/fileBytes])
```

and get the output:

**524894  896189009  1707.37141022759**

What is taking up the extra 895,664,115 bytes? I know the help page says there should be a little extra overhead, but I feel that nearly a Gb of descriptive header is a bit excessive!

**New information:**
I tried pre-allocating the file, thinking that perhaps MATLAB was doing the same thing it does when a matrix is embiggened in a loop and reallocating a chunk of disk space for the entire matrix on each write, and that isn't it. Filling the file with zeros of the appropriate data types results in a file that my short check script returns:

**8531570  71467  0.00837677004349727**

This makes more sense to me. Matlab is saving the file sparsely, so the disk file size is much smaller than the size of the full matrix in memory. Once it starts replacing values with real data, however, I get the same behavior as before and the file size starts skyrocketing beyond all reasonable bounds.

**New new information:**
Tried this on a subset of the data, 100 lines long. To stream to disk, the data has to be in v7.3 format, so I ran the subset through my script, loaded it into memory, and then resaved as v7.0 format.  Here are the results:

*v7.3:* **3800  8752  2.30**
*v7.0:* **3800  2561  0.67**

No wonder the v7.3 format isn't the default. Does anyone know a way around this? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: What does your OS say how much space is really used on disk?

Comment: 857,185Kb (Windows 7 64-bit, MATLAB 2013a 64-bit)

Comment: Sure seems like a bug to me, but you can get around it by writing in chunks.  I tried it for chunks of 10,000 and the file is reasonably sized.

Comment: I too find the `v7.3` compression, or lack thereof, is the in the pits.  I recall complaining about this to MathWorks sometime ago and got some response about overhead!

Comment: Why are you using matfile to save the data?  Why not just use the save function?

Comment: This test file I'm working with could probably all fit into memory, but this was a test case for the full HITRAN 2012 database which is  a 700 Mb text file. After loading that into memory, and then parcelling it out into different variables, and then saving it to disk, it brings my computer to its knees. The first time I tried it, I had to do a hard reset and lost a bunch of other work.

Comment: I'd say this is a great reason _not_ to use `matfile` if you have enough memory to avoid it.

Comment: That's the trick. I don't have enough memory to avoid it. My main goal here is to convert the data file into a matlab binary where I could load in a single variable, let's say the line frequency or molecule, search on a criteria, like a range or isotope, and then only load in that part of the database that satisfies the criteria. In native text form, I would have to load the entire thing into memory (or do a line-by-line search, which takes a lot of time. If I can get it into a reasonable sized binary compatible with the `matfile` command, that saves time and memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a bug to me. A workaround is to **write in chunks** to pre-allocated arrays.

Start off by pre-allocating:

```
fid = fopen('01_hit12.par', 'r');
data = fread(fid, inf, 'uint8');
nlines = nnz(data == 10) + 1;
fclose(fid);

matObj.moleculeNumber = zeros(1,nlines,'uint8');
matObj.isotopeologueNumber = zeros(1,nlines,'uint8');
matObj.vacuumWavenumber = zeros(1,nlines,'double');
matObj.lineIntensity = zeros(1,nlines,'double');
matObj.airWidth = zeros(1,nlines,'single');
matObj.selfWidth = zeros(1,nlines,'single');
matObj.lowStateE = zeros(1,nlines,'single');
matObj.tempDependWidth = zeros(1,nlines,'single');
matObj.pressureShift = zeros(1,nlines,'single');
```

Then to write in chunks of 10000, I modified your code as follows:

```
... % your code plus pre-alloc first
bs = 10000;
while ischar(hitranTemp)
    if abs(hitranTemp(1)) == 32;
        hitranTemp(1) = '0';
    end

    for ii = 1:bs,
        hitran{ii} = textscan(hitranTemp,'%2u%1u%12f%10f%10f%5f%5f%10f%4f%8f%15c%15c%15c%15c%6u%2u%2u%2u%2u%2u%2    u%1c%7f%7f','delimiter','','whitespace','');
        hitranTemp = fgetl(fidr);
        if hitranTemp==-1, bs=ii; break; end
    end

    % this part really ugly, sorry! trying to keep it compact...
    matObj.moleculeNumber(1,k:k+bs-1)      = uint8(builtin('_paren',cellfun(@(c)c{1},hitran),1:bs));
    matObj.isotopeologueNumber(1,k:k+bs-1) = uint8(builtin('_paren',cellfun(@(c)c{2},hitran),1:bs));
    matObj.vacuumWavenumber(1,k:k+bs-1)    = builtin('_paren',cellfun(@(c)c{3},hitran),1:bs);
    matObj.lineIntensity(1,k:k+bs-1)       = builtin('_paren',cellfun(@(c)c{4},hitran),1:bs);
    matObj.airWidth(1,k:k+bs-1)            = single(builtin('_paren',cellfun(@(c)c{5},hitran),1:bs));
    matObj.selfWidth(1,k:k+bs-1)           = single(builtin('_paren',cellfun(@(c)c{6},hitran),1:bs));
    matObj.lowStateE(1,k:k+bs-1)           = single(builtin('_paren',cellfun(@(c)c{7},hitran),1:bs));
    matObj.tempDependWidth(1,k:k+bs-1)     = single(builtin('_paren',cellfun(@(c)c{8},hitran),1:bs));
    matObj.pressureShift(1,k:k+bs-1)       = single(builtin('_paren',cellfun(@(c)c{9},hitran),1:bs));

    k = k + bs;
    fprintf('.');
end
fclose(fidr);
```

The final size on disk is 21,393,408 bytes. The usage breaks down as,

```
>> S = whos('-file','01_hit12.mat');
>> fileBytes = sum([S.bytes]);
>> T = dir(which('01_hit12.mat'));
>> diskBytes = T.bytes; ratio = diskBytes/fileBytes;
>> fprintf('%10d whos\n%10d disk\n%10.6f\n',fileBytes,diskBytes,ratio)
   8531608 whos
  21389582 disk
  2.507099
```

Still fairly inefficient, but not out of control.

Comment: I have a version of this running overnight (not that it will take that long, but I ran it before I left work). In the morning I will either have a 20Mb file that I can work with, or else a 30Gb monstrosity that will eat my hard drive. While you are paying attention to the subject and have the datafile, I would appreciate it if you could take a look at the linked question I posted last week about MATLAB gobbling the leading space when using `textscan` (thus the `if(abs(hitranTemp)==32);hitranTemp(1)='0';end` block). Do you see the same thing when you parse the data?

Comment: It should already be done by now.  :)  It only took a few minutes on my machine since there are only about 20 writes instead of >200,000.

Comment: My computer is only 6 months old, but it still runs pretty slow for me. I started it running and by the time I had gathered up my stuff to leave, it was still chugging away.

Comment: That did it! In fact, when it was finished, the file sizes were 8531570 whos, 7263675 disk, for a ratio of 0.851388.